# How to set default umask in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: permissions, 17.04, .profile, gnome-session, umask

In the past, I have always set `umask` at `~/.profile`. I set a `umask` of `077` so my documents get a permission of `600 (rw-------)`. But setting this at `~/.profile` no longer works in Ubuntu 17.04.

So as new documents get created in a gnome session on Ubuntu 17.04, where can I configure so that they get created with permission 600?

Answer (score 6):

To set permissions for all directories and files that are created day-forward by any user:

1. sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-session
2. Find the line with "session optional pam_umask.so"
3. Change this to "session optional pam_umask.so umask=0077"
4. Save the file.
5. Reboot.

New files will be 600.
New directories will be 700.

Comment: Except for the bug in the default GNOME terminal linked to in Daniel's answer, this works, but I'm curious why you're suggesting modifying `/etc/pam.d/common-session` directly, given that the value is primarily defined in `/etc/login.defs` (at least as of 18.04 - has that changed)?

Comment: @mklement0 Probably because of the comment in the default `.profile`: _"for setting the umask for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package"_

Comment: The OP ask for a per user setting, not for any user.

Answer (score 5):

**tl; dr:** Replace `UMASK 022` by e.g. `UMASK 027` in file `/etc/login.defs` but doesn't work 100%.

---

## Documentation

See the [man pages (20.04)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/pam_umask.8.html) for info on this. There are several places where it can be set: I used `/etc/pam.d/login` or `/etc/default/login` in the past but stopped working so now I'm using `/etc/login.defs` which *partially* works.

> The PAM module tries to get the umask value from the following places in the following order:
>
> ·   umask= entry in the user's GECOS field
>
> ·   umask= argument
>
> ·   UMASK entry from /etc/login.defs (influenced by USERGROUPS_ENAB in /etc/login.defs)
>
> ·   UMASK= entry from /etc/default/login
>
> (...)
>
> EXAMPLES
>
> Add the following line to /etc/pam.d/login to set the user specific umask at login:
>
> ```
>     session optional pam_umask.so umask=0022
> ```

## Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 20.04

In file `/etc/login.defs` there is an entry `UMASK      022` that can be replaced by, in my case, `UMASK        027`. Then reboot. This yields:

#### Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ umask
0022
$ more /etc/login.defs | grep ^UMASK
UMASK       027

$ echo foo > terminal

NOTE:  Open gedit from Dock and write file `dock`
       Open gedit from Menu and write file `menu`

$ ls -l dock menu terminal
-rw-r--r-- 1 daniel daniel 4 nov  4 16:11 dock
-rw-rw---- 1 daniel daniel 4 nov  4 16:11 menu
-rw-r--r-- 1 daniel daniel 4 nov  4 16:11 terminal
```

#### Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ umask
0007
$ more /etc/login.defs | grep ^UMASK
UMASK       027

$ ls -l foo bar
ls: cannot access 'foo': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'bar': No such file or directory

$ touch foo
$ echo hello > bar
$ ls -l foo bar
-rw-rw---- 1 daniel daniel 6 nov  4 17:20 bar
-rw-rw---- 1 daniel daniel 0 nov  4 17:20 foo
```

## Might work in 17.04

Note this file does not exist on my version of Ubuntu, in which case we can create it.

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'session optional pam_umask.so umask=0027' >> /etc/default/login"

$ more /etc/default/login
session optional pam_umask.so umask=0027
```

## Evil Bug

Now if we restart and ask for the umask in the terminal we still get `0022` (in the case of Ubuntu 18.04) and not the `0027` that was set. See [Bug #1685754](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1685754).

But if we open an application, for example the Text Editor, and save a file we'll notice the new umask affected permissions. Open it from the menu, not from the terminal as it seems to pick up the (bad) `umask` from the terminal.

## References

- [Ubuntu 18.04 Manpage for `pam_umask`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/pam_umask.8.html)
- [Bug #1685754, since 17.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1685754)

Comment: Good to know about the bug. Is there a reason you're not modifying the `UMASK` value directly in the preexisting `/etc/login.defs` file (or does that work differently in 17.04)? Also, you mention `/etc/pam.d/login` in the text, but your command modifies `/etc/default/login`.

Comment: @mklement0, I don't remember the reason. I used `/etc/default/login` or `/etc/pam.d/login` in the past and these seemed to somehow work for some time, but not anymore. I now did a new installation with Ubuntu 20.04 and the same issue come up, I'm now using `/etc/login.defs`. The man page states all of these configuration files affect permissions.

Comment: The OP asked for a per-user configuration. The man page only talks about "GECOS fields" without any link or explanation how to modify them.

Comment: thats because in /etc/logindefs; if 'USERGROUPS_ENAB yes' then user and private user group permissions (uid= <user>, gid = <user>) will be same. i.e. 022 will be implemented as 002, or 027 as 007, 077 as 007...so on

Answer (score 2):

I have recently came across this on Ubuntu 20.04 TLS and found the solution.

```
$ man -k umask
$ man pam_umask
```

This will get us the location of manual pages that discuss umask - all information can be found there.

From **/etc/pam.d/common-session**:

> The pam_umask module will set the umask according to the system
> default in /etc/login.defs and user settings.
>
> This solves the problem of different umask settings with different
> shells, display managers, remote sessions etc.

From PAM_UMASK(8):

> pam_umask is a PAM module to set the file mode creation mask of the
> current environment. The PAM module tries to get the umask value from
> the following places in the following order:
>
> umask= entry in the user's GECOS field
>
> umask= argument UMASK entry
>
> from /etc/login.defs (influenced by USERGROUPS_ENAB in
> /etc/login.defs)
>
> UMASK= entry from /etc/default/login

Notice the text in the brackets: **influenced by USERGROUPS_ENAB in /etc/login.defs.**

What is USERGROUPS_ENAB?

From **/etc/login.defs**:

> If USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", that will modify this UMASK
> default value
> for private user groups, i. e. the uid is the same as gid, and username is
> the same as the primary group name: for these, the user permissions will be
> used as group permissions, e. g. 022 will become 002.
>
> In not specified, the permission mask (umask) is initialized to 022.

You can now run this:

```
$ sudo nl /etc/login.defs | grep USERGROUPS_ENAB
```

to double-check if you have USERGROUPS_ENAB set to "yes", if it's uncommented (default), and on which line of the document can you find it.

Therefore, when you change the default "UMASK  022" to "UMASK  027", if USERGROUPS_ENAB is set to "yes", you will see that your umask has been set to 007 (not 027) - as it ignores the 2nd position (group permissions).

The solution to this is simple: uncomment the line where "USERGROUPS_ENAB" is set to "yes". If you have changed umask value to "UMASK  027", you will have umask set to 027 after the reboot.

You can verify this by running this in your shell.

```
$ umask
```

To summarize, the only config file that matters is **/etc/login.defs**.

Set your umask to desired value and make sure to uncomment USERGROUPS_ENAB line to change group permissions as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022
```

That's literally what your `~/.profile` says. Did you relogin once changed? It should work fine.

Also:

```
This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists.
```

Actually confirmed the issue on a freshly installed ubuntu 17.04. Even fully updating still causes this issue to arise and even `~/.bash_profile`is ignored, there seems to be an issue with the command interpreter not reading those files after login.

You can use `~/.bashrc` for now, which still works fine and is read during login.

So after digging a little into it, it seems bash is not run by default with the --login anymore which means it doesn't read the ~/.profile. Starting a new bash with the umask in ~/.profile with `bash --login` sets the umask correctly starting a bash without it though ignores the ~/.profile. Not sure what was changed but this seems like a bug to me unless it was intentionally changed.

Comment: Yes, I relogged in.

Comment: And the only ~/.bash files I have are .bashrc, .bash_logout, .bash_history. I ran a find search. .bash_profile and .bash_login do NOT exist on machine.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry you are actually right. I just freshly installed a 17.04 to test it on a new installation and it actually isn't read from ~/.profile for some reason. I haven't digged into it yet. But you can add your umask into `~/.bashrc` for now this is still read during startup.

Comment: Ziazis, setting umask in .bashrc only works for docs created in terminal. I'm looking to get umask applied for example from doc created in gedit. You have found a fix with `bash -login`? How do I implement this exactly? Or is this unfixable until a bug is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GDM, it doesn't read `~/.profile` like LightDM does. And the terminal normally opens a non-login shell. The net effect is that `~/.profile` is not loaded at all when you open a terminal after logging in using GDM.

Either:

- put your settings in `~/.bashrc`, or
- set your terminal to start a login shell, or
- switch to LightDM

Comment: Actually I just confirmed his issue on a freshly installed 17.04 version. Has nothing to do with GDM since by default lightDM is still used.

Comment: OK, so? Did I say his issue doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04.3 I have tried to create `/etc/default/login` with `session optional pam_umask.so umask=0027` as Daniel says but not worked for me, instead I have changed the umask in `/etc/login.defs` and it worked.

I have changed umask value in 002 and now all the users create files with full permission also for their own group.

Answer (score 0):

I have the workaround at least on Fedora 31:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/umask.sh
umask <your_umask>

sudo vi /etc/login.defs
UMASK <your_umask>

sudo vi /usr/local/bin/systemd-user
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/systemd-user

sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service
ExecStart=-/usr/local/bin/systemd-user
```